# why the value for string shows in capital for the first print but then show small in second print?

Tags: java, string

I know that strings are immutable, but how this work

```
    String s1 = "Java";
    System.out.println(s1.toUpperCase()); //will show in capital

    String s2="Stack overflow";
    s2.toUpperCase();
    System.out.println(s2); //won't show in capital
```

Comment: Because you don't assign `s2.toUpperCase()` to s2.

Comment: @forpas but why s1 worked and i didn't assign it to s1.

Comment: Because you didn't print `s1`, you printed the result of `s1.toUpperCase()`.

Comment: You print `s1.toUpperCase()` not `s1`.

Comment: ohhhh how did i mistaken that, thank you guys.